# Is there a method similar to RegisterClassHandler for DependencyProperty values?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I know that you can use the `EventManager` class to register a class handler to a routed event to get all instances of a class to respond when that event is fired for that class object:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler( typeof( TextBox ), Control.MouseDoubleClickEvent,
    new RoutedEventHandler( ( S, E ) => ( E.OriginalSource as TextBox )?.SelectAll( ) ) );
```

What I am looking for is a way to do something similar with an attached `DependencyProperty` to provide a `DataBinding` to all instances of a control type which use that particular property.

In compliance with the [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) requirements...

App.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MCVE {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FooProperty;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        static App( ) {
            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(
                typeof( TextBox ), Control.MouseDoubleClickEvent,
                new RoutedEventHandler(
                    ( S, E ) => ( E.OriginalSource as TextBox )?.SelectAll( ) ) );
            FooProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                    "Foo", typeof( string ), typeof( App) );
            //Is it possible to bind the FooProperty of all Window objects to
            //the FooSource property defined below in similar fashion 
            //to how one can call RegisterClassHandler above?
        }

        [STAThread]
        public static int Main( ) {
            App program = new App( );
            program.InitializeComponent( );
            return program.Run( );
        }

        protected override void OnStartup( StartupEventArgs e ) {
            this.FooSource = "Baz";
            base.OnStartup( e );
        }

        public static string GetFoo( Window w ) =>
            w.GetValue( FooProperty ).ToString( );
        public static void SetFoo( Window w, string value ) =>
            w.SetValue( FooProperty, value );

        private string _fooSource = "Bar";
        public string FooSource {
            get => this._fooSource;
            set {
                this._fooSource = value;
                this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
                    this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( "FooSource" ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the desired behavior would be that, after launching the program, any window created afterward would have the `FooProperty` value set to `"Baz"` via some data binding behavior ( so that if the `FooSource` property changed, then each windows `FooProperty` property would also change ).

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know if I can answer that quickly. But this looks a lot like an oberser pattern would fix your problem? Or did I misunderstand the problem?

Comment: @MortenBork I'm not even a little sure I know what you mean by "Observer Pattern"...

Anyway - the problem is outlined in the question - every single instance of, in this example, a "window", that is created should ultimately have its attached `Foo` property bound to the specified `FooSource` property, preferably without my having to specify for each window in the XAML. I mean, I can do it, and that's how I currently AM doing it, but because of the `EventManager` method, it feels to me that there aught to be some way of just saying "Each window has this value bound to this property".

Comment: http://www.dofactory.com/net/observer-design-pattern

Comment: I don't know of any specific method but you can do it via binding's relative source property. or you can put foo property inside a singleton object or even a resx

Comment: What about having a custom window with a custom DP ? also if you are doing MVVM, each window can have a separate datacontext so the binding will be breaked. What is the real purpose of this property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add one more event handler for `Window.Loaded` event in `App`'s  constructor.

```
private App()
{
    EventManager.ResisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), Window.LoadedEvent,
        (RoutedEventHandler)((s, e) =>
            ((Windows)s).SetBinding(FooProperty, new Binding("FooSource")
            {
                Source = this,
            }
        ));
}
```

And I believe that it just a careless miss, the owner type of `FooProperty` should be `typeof(App)` but not `typeof(Window)`.